# JPA Canonical MetaModels not being detected

Tags: jpa, eclipselink

I am (have to) manually create Canonical MetaModels but they are not being detected by EclipseLink and cause a Null Pointer whenever I try and use them.

When loading the application I see this message for all my entities 
`[EL Finer]: ... --Canonical Metamodel class [<class name>_] not found during initialization.`

All of the Entities and their Canonical metamodels are in the same package and level, and the metamodels all have the `@StaticMetaModel(RealEntity.class)` annotation, am I missing something else?

Does it have to do with how I'm scanning the packages maybe? Or is using MetaModels not possible without one of the processors/generators?

Comment: If you use eclipse click over the project /JPA/ Canonical metamodel and select src folder 
so the metamodel will be generated automatically and it will be detected.

Comment: Check that you do not have self-translation in the browser, because it is in English.